# How to effectively split a large phpunit testsuite?

Tags: phpunit, test-suite

I use phpunit's testsuites feature to organize my tests. I do so to have the ability to run tests in parallel later on.

This is relatively straight forward for different directories. So i could split up testsuites by bundle for example.

```
<testsuite name="bundle-one">
    <directory>tests/BundleOne</directory>
</testsuite>

<testsuite name="bundle-two">
    <directory>tests/BundleTwo</directory>
</testsuite>

<testsuite name="bundle-three">
    <directory>tests/BundleThree</directory>
</testsuite>
```

But now i have one single directory (services) which contains dozens of sub-folders. I could manually make several testsuites our of this folder. But this would be a weak solution in my opinions. Because the testsuites could break easily if i mention every sub-folder in them and the folders get renamed or removed.

My idea was to use some kind of regular expression to select a range of sub-folders to include in one testsuite and another range of folders for another testsuite.

```
<testsuite name="services-AM">
    <directory>tests/services/{A-M}</directory>
</testsuite>

<testsuite name="services-NZ">
    <directory>tests/services/{A-M}</directory>
</testsuite>
```

I could not find any documentation on my idea. Does anybody might have an idea for this ? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if there's a way to do this "on-the-fly" but you could automate the process of creating these bundles from reg-ex:

In composer.json:

```
 "scripts": {
    "make-phpunit-bundles": "php path/to/myscript.php"
},
```

before running tests:

```
php composer.phar make-phpunit-bundles
```

myscript.php:

```
//Iterate/scan your directories, build and write the phpunit.xml file 
//based on the regular expressions you want
```

Answer (score 7):

An easier solution may be to filter your tests:

```
# Only include test classes beginning with the letter A-M
phpunit --filter '/^[A-M]/'
```

and

```
# Only include test classes beginning with the letter N-Z
phpunit --filter '/^[N-Z]/'
```

Assuming all your test classes start with a capital letter.

You will need to experiment to get an even split. i.e. if all your tests start with characters between `A-M` then this won't work.

*Tested with PHPUnit 5.4.6*